# Collider2d.bounds.Intersects not detecting intersection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm making a top-down game where you drive a car and shoot targets at the same time. I have a script that makes a sprite of a crosshair follows the mouse cursor and I want to have it set up so that when the player presses the mouse button (the mouse button isn't in the code now) and the crosshair sprite is overlapping an enemy sprite, the enemy dies. I was following [this documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Intersects.html?_ga=2.190562347.1601715734.1612817199-1967396109.1612817199) on Bounds.Intersects. Here's my code:

```
public class shootingScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject target, enemy;
    CircleCollider2D targetCollider;
    CapsuleCollider2D enemyCollider;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Check that the first GameObject exists in the Inspector and fetch the Collider
        if (target != null)
        {
            print("targ not null");
            targetCollider = target.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
        }
        //Check that the second GameObject exists in the Inspector and fetch the Collider
        if (enemy != null)
        {
            print("enemy not null");
            enemyCollider = enemy.GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (targetCollider.bounds.Intersects(enemyCollider.bounds))
        {
            print("hit");
            Destroy(enemy);
        }
    }
}
```

In-game "targ not null" and  "enemy not null" prints but when I move my cursor and the crosshair goes over the enemy "hit" is not printed and the enemy is not destroyed. I have a CircleCollider2D on the crosshair and a CapsuleCollider2D on the enemy. The script is on an empty game object. I also tried sprite.bounds but that resulted in the enemy getting killed as soon as I run the game.

EDIT:
Here's the code that keeps the crosshair sprite on the cursor. I copied it from somewhere. I set moveSpeed to 99999 since I want the crosshair sprite to be exactly where the mouse is.

```
public class mouseReticle : MonoBehaviour
{

private Vector3 mousePosition;
public float moveSpeed = 0.1f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
    transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mousePosition, moveSpeed);
}
}
```

Comment: Please include enough info to reproduce the problem, including how to set up the scene. See [mre] for more information.

Comment: Agree with @Ruzihm please add the exact code you are using in particular that crosshair movement and I think it would help to see your sceneview and Inspector settings of both objects in the moment you think there should be an intersection

Comment: The target sprite and enemy sprite were at different depths my bad. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

The target sprite and enemy sprite were at different depths (z).